# Get property Type and convert String to corresponding Type

Tags: c#, csom

I am using CSOM to update some Task of a Project Server Project.

Which property has to be updated is not defined the code finds out dynamically what to update based on the property name as String.

For better understanding I wore a simplified version of my code

```
//fieldName = "ActualWorkTimeSpan"; value = "16:00:00";
private void Start(string fieldName, string value)
{
    DraftTask draftTask = GetDraftTask();

    Update(draftTask, fieldName, value);

    PublishAndCheckin(draftTask);
}

private static void Update(DraftTask draftTask, string fieldName, string value)
{
    // skip updating if field is Equal
    if (GetPropValue(draftTask, fieldName).ToString() == value)
        return;

    // update of the task
    SetPropValue(draftTask, fieldName, value);

}

private static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}

private static void SetPropValue(DraftTask src, string propName, object value)
{
    src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(src, value);
}
```

I can use `GetPropValue()` without problem but for `SetPropValue()` I would need the value to be in the right type.

In this case it would be "System.TimeSpan" for the property "ActualWorkTimeSpan". So I would need to convert the string "15:00:00" to TimeSpan.

It would be easy to do if it were TimeSpan every time, but I could be that the Field "Cost" is set to be updated.

```
Update(draftTask, "Cost", "500");
```

So my question is if it is Possible to find out what type the field has and than convert my value to the same type.

Comment: Why do you need it to be in the right type? `SetValue` takes an `object` type anyway.

Comment: Also, I don't think you understand what the `ref` keyword does, I suggest you go read up on that too.

Comment: @DavidG; only if the target property is an object as well. His source data is always a string, so it clearly has to be converted first

Comment: @Tewr OP is using reflection, the parameters of [`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx) are `object`. I'm not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: `SetPropValue` takes parameter `object value` but this is always being called with a string. I suggest the method signature is changed if this is always going to be the case.

Comment: @DavidG I am suggestion that the target class DraftTask has a property signature `public TimeSpan ActualWorkTimeSpan`. If you call SetValue with a string on that property, it will fail at runtime without conversion.

Comment: @Tewr Yes, and as CalC suggests, it's the value that is passed in that is the problem. The method should be changed to take an `object`, or even make it generic.

Comment: What's the reason why all your data is in string in the first place?

Comment: Btw, instead of ``"ActualWorkTimeSpan"`` you used use ``nameof(DraftTask.ActualWorkTimeSpan)`` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof

Comment: @RandRandom, his question is simplified. "(...)which property has to be updated is not defined the code finds out dynamically what to update based on the property name".

Comment: Can you clarify if you are looking to parse string values or otherwise? Also, why are you using reflection?

Comment: Your check for equality is also **seriously** flawed.  If the `Type` doesn't override `ToString` it will always compare the values based on the name of the `Type`, so objects will ALWAYS return as being unequal, unless the value is literally the name of the `Type`.

Comment: @RandRandom - you are totally correct. However, if the OP can do that, they *really* shouldn't be using reflection. I can only assume the fieldnames are in a drop down or config file and that `Update(ref draftTask, "ActualWorkTimeSpan", "15:00:00");` is just an example

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. First yes the Update() is just an example. I will change it a bit later to clarify things. The ref could also be removed from my example. About the equality check I am still just trying around at the moment so it is fine. I am still learning thanks again for all your feedback.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use [`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtxwhzx(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a `Type` and returns a `TypeConverter` that knows how to convert a `string` to the specified `Type`.

You can then call [`TypeConverter.ConvertFromString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25ds5cb6(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the string to the required `Type`.

Your code would look like:

```
var propType = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).PropertyType;
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propType);
var convertedObject = converter.ConvertFromString(src);
```

Comment: This will work of course but it'really just papering over the fact that the method signature is wrong in the first place.

Comment: it throws :
System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, by using [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method.

```
private static void SetPropValue(DraftTask src, string propName, object value)
{
    var property = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
    var valueToSet = Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType);
    property.SetValue(src, valueToSet);
}
```

**ref**, is useless in this case. It is used when you assign the parameter in the called method and have it also be assigned at the calling site (the scope of the calling method).

Comment: ``and assign new object to that object`` should be ``and assign new object to that reference``

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to change the method signature to be generic or take an  `object` type and actually pass in the correct data type in the first place. For example:

```
private static void Update(DraftTask draftTask, string fieldName, object value)
{
    //snip
}
```

Or generic:

```
private static void Update<T>(DraftTask draftTask, string fieldName, T value)
{
    //snip
}
```

And now you call it with the correct type, for example:

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(...);
Update(ref draftTask, "ActualWorkTimeSpan", timeSpan);
```